# How do you use a Controller within a blade/error.php file?

Tags: laravel-8

When I try App::make('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController') I just get server error 500 (and nothing else more helpful)

Comment: Why you think you need that? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now it's just app('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController');

But for most pages I can pass $this into the view from the controller to have access to it on the view